Why does the character encoding of HTML source code need to match the one declared in the meta charset tag?
The title very much describes the question. The HTML standard says explicitly that the only value acceptable for the <meta charset> tag is UTF-8, and even the Nu Html Checker throws an error if any other value is used. But, it also throws another error at the same time:

Internal encoding declaration iso-8859-1 disagrees with the actual encoding of the document (utf-8)

I used the value 'iso-8859-1' in the <meta> charset this time.
If the only value we can use is UTF-8, I just can't understand the need to state this as a rule to follow.
The HTML standard itself doesn't say much about this, and the encoding standard of Whatwg is too technical for me to read and find out myself, so I need help understanding this.

This seems to be an X/Y question. WHY would you use anything else than UTF8? It is much safer to convert your old files to utf8 than to send them as iso-8859-1. Also the error you are getting is likely because you send utf8 but have set the charset to iso-8859-1 - possibly for legacy reasons

@mplungjan  " Also the error you are getting is likely because you send utf8 but have set the charset to iso-8859-1 "   -  but then, when i specifically use the textpad to change the encoding to utf16 BE, and then tried, even then as long as the charset value was utf-8 no errors at all, but when change it to utf-16be 2 errors, one was the same utf-8, and other error was different this time saying  " Internal encoding declaration specified utf-16be which is not an ASCII superset. Continuing as if the encoding had been utf-8 "

I do not know and I do not actually need to find out. I can only suggest you don't do that then. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Ef-wqM9WAAALX80.jpg

I am still very much curious about WHY you want to do this when it seems to be fitting a round peg in a square hole... If it is as an exercise, then OK, but it is going to give you grief. I have been there with French EBCDIC and ISO to early browsers and to standardise on utf8 end-to-end was such a relief

@mplungjan honestly, i just want to know the reason, the real rigrous/documented reason. I am not a typical engineer, infact this is more like a side-quest, i want to understand the web in n out...  doesn't matter how much rfcs or specs i need to go through.....  btw i still haven't found an answer on my own to this problem, i hope i'll find it sometime soon....... unless someone answers it here....

@mplungjan now you're trying too hard bro,  llms seriously! (not to mention that asker themselves would prefer to ask llms all they can first, only when it seems ambigous will they turn to SO);  no one's judging you man, just let it go, no web-dev  can possibly know everything about web, not even the people who maintain the specs....    that being said, if you get a authentic, documented piece of information i would be happy to consider it.......

The documentation said: Don't, because standards. You insist in violating them and want to know why they puke or why they sometimes don't puke, then it's on you. I am not sure who is trying too hard here ;). Just trying to help




Why does the character encoding of HTML source code need to match the one declared in the meta charset tag?

Because of consistency. Parsers have multiple hints to get to know the text encoding:

HTTP header Content-Type (RFC 9110)
using its subtype token charset= and one of IANA's registered Character Sets (f.e.
UTF-8).
A (pseudo) BOM in the payload's bytes, unrelated to if one should avoid them or not (f.e. 0xEF BB BF for UTF-8) and unbound to how the bytes must be treated.
A markup attribute when treating the bytes as text (this implies the parser already had partial success in treating the bytes as text), such as:

<?xml encoding="UTF-8" for XML or
<meta charset="UTF-8" for HTML5 or
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" for HTML4.01 or else.



When you declare an encoding in the HTML/XML markup it definitly makes no sense to write something different than what the actual encoding is - that would just be lying. What's the benefit to encode the text in f.e. UTF-16BE and then saying in the markup that it should be UTF16-LE?



The HTML standard says explicitly that the only value acceptable for the <meta charset> tag is UTF-8

That's the HTML5 standard as of today, for both:

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content= and
<meta charset=.

But in the past the HTML5.2 specs did not limit it to UTF-8 only. Likewise HTML4.01 and XHTML1 don't know that limitation either.



the Nu Html Checker throws an error if any other value is used

The HTML5.2 specs even define this to further guide everyone onto using UTF-8 only:

Authors should use UTF-8. Conformance checkers may advise authors against using legacy encodings.




If the only value we can use is UTF-8, I just can't understand the need to state this as a rule to follow.

See it as a fallback to make it extra clear that your text is and should be treated as UTF-8. There may enough (legacy) parsers which aren't perfect, or which would never guess a text encoding at all (but at the same time cannot distinguish that precisely HTML5 from HTML4.01 and XHTML to then know and assume only UTF-8 is allowed for the former). The declaration is also a double check to authors if they really understand what they type there, giving a hint to the last idiot as in "wait - when I declare this document as UTF-8 - have I really saved it as such...? Is my HTTP server really sending the correct headers?".



You're still free to use other text encodings, but then you can't use HTML5 (or XHTML5). Nobody is holding you back to either use HTML4.01 or XHTML1. See also Declaring character encodings in HTML, mentioning additional hints on why UTF-8 is the way to go and how the markup declaration makes sense:


The declaration should fit completely within the first 1024 bytes at the start of the file
the HTTP header has a higher precedence than the in-document meta declarations, content authors should always take into account whether the character encoding is already declared in the HTTP header. If it is, the meta element must be set to declare the same encoding.
If you have a UTF-8 byte-order mark (BOM) at the start of your file then modern browsers will use that to determine that the encoding of your page is UTF-8. It has a higher precedence than any other declaration, including the HTTP header.
The XML declaration is only required if the page is not being served as UTF-8
The HTML5 specification forbids the use of the meta element to declare UTF-16, because the values must be ASCII-compatible. Instead you should ensure that you always have a byte-order mark at the very start of a UTF-16 encoded file. In effect, this is the in-document declaration.


It also links to Choosing & applying a character encoding:


must not use JIS_C6226-1983, JIS_X0212-1990, HZ-GB-2312, JOHAB (Windows code page 1361), encodings based on ISO-2022, or encodings based on EBCDIC ... because ... poses a security threat.
must also not use CESU-8, UTF-7, BOCU-1, or SCSU encodings, since they were never intended for Web content and the HTML5 specification forbids browsers from recognising them.
strongly discourages ... UTF-16, ... UTF-32
Other ... should also be avoided. These include Big5 and EUC-JP ... ISO-8859-8


